# Linear ordering and cardinal numbers - Problem 5.3 Jech's book

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, well-orders

I am solving problems of the Jech's book (set theory). I need help to solve problem 5.3: Let $(P, <)$ be a linear ordering and let κ be a cardinal. If every initial segment of $P$ has cardinality $< κ$, then $|P | ≤ κ$. I have the following idea, but  it seems it isn't correct path.
Let $P$ a linearly ordered set and $\kappa$ a cardinal such that for
all $x\in P$, the initial segment $P_{x}=\{y\in P:y<x\}$ is of size less
than $\kappa$.
If $M$ is a greatest element of $P$, then
clearly $|P|=|P_{M}\cup\{M\}|=1+|P_{M}|\leq\kappa$ since $|P_{M}|<\kappa$.
Otherwise, let $x_{0}<x_{1}<...x_{\alpha}<...$ an enumeration of P of
size $\lambda=|P|$. Then for
all $\alpha<\lambda$, $|\alpha|=|P_{{x_{\alpha}}}|<\kappa$ thus $\alpha<\kappa$. Since P does not have a greatest element, $\lambda$ is limit
i.e. $\lambda=\sup_{{\alpha<\lambda}}\alpha\leq\kappa$.
Again $|P|\leq\kappa$.
Do you have a solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

For $a\in P$ define $P_a:=\{b\in P: b\le a\}.$ So the premise of theorem says that $|P_a|<\kappa$ for all $a\in P.$

Assume, contrary to the conclusion, that $|P|>\kappa,$ and define a sequence $(a_\alpha:\alpha\le\kappa)$ in $P$ by recursion by letting $a_\alpha\in P$ be some element strictly greater than all of $\{a_\beta :\beta <\alpha\}.$ Such an element exists since $\bigcup_{\beta < \alpha}P_{a_\beta}$ is a union of no more than $\kappa$ sets of size less than $\kappa,$ so has size $\le \kappa<|P|.$

But then, since $a_\kappa$ is greater than all of $\{a_\alpha: \alpha < \kappa\}$ we have $|P_{a_\kappa}|\ge \kappa,$ which contradicts the premise.

Comment: Hello, it is a nice idea!